# Python: Export the tabulate output data into csv file

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, numpy, beautifulsoup

I want to store HTML table data into CSV file.

I wrote the following code using python, selenium, BeautifulSoup, pandas, tabulate, numpy.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
import numpy as np     
#---Some code are here
datalist2 = []
for i in range(1, total+1):
    xpath="/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr["+str(i)+"]/td[1]/a/img"
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
    print("Open button " + str(i) + " Clicked")
    soup_level2=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    table2=soup_level2.find_all('table')[0]
    df2=pd.read_html(str(table2),header=0)
    datalist2.append(df2[0])
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    print("moving_back_to_previous_page")   
for i in range(len(datalist2)):
        print(tabulate(datalist2[i]))
#text_file=open("output.csv","w")
#text_file.write(str(datalist2))
#text_file.close()  
#print("report generated and saved")
#np.savetxt("output.csv", datalist2, delimiter=",", fmt='%s')
```

This code `print(tabulate(datalist2[i]))` displays the table data in console.

Sample output of `print(tabulate(datalist2[i]))`

```
 0  Date Crashed    nan  2018-10-09 07:56:49 UTC
 1  Date Reported   nan  2018-10-09 07:56:57 UTC
 2  Date Built      nan  2018-06-06 01:26:35 UTC
 3  Crash Reason    nan  SIGSEGV
 4  Crash Addr      nan  0x0
 5  Dump file name  nan  9556393da77a562fa086b0147a37106c6ff4bb76_mac14B7F66_dat2018-10-09-07-56-49_boxXB6_modC40COM_54dc2dd1-9abe-a568-1e3119e4-1908ccb0.dmp.tgz
```

This code `text_file.write(str(datalist2))` stores the datalist2 into CSV file. There is a problem with this code. It does not show the long text. For example, index 5 could not show the Dump file name completely.
Sample output of `text_file.write(str(datalist2))`

```
0     Date Crashed         NaN                            2018-10-09 07:56:49 UTC
1    Date Reported         NaN                            2018-10-09 07:56:57 UTC
2       Date Built         NaN                            2018-06-06 01:26:35 UTC
3     Crash Reason         NaN                                            SIGSEGV
4       Crash Addr         NaN                                                0x0
5   Dump file name         NaN  9556393da77a562fa086b0147a37106c6ff4bb76_mac14...
```

I also want to remove the index column and the second column contains 'nan' as value.
I want to store this data into CSV file. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

To remove the index column and the second column containing empty values displayed as 'NaN'

```
soup_level2=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
table2=soup_level2.find_all('table')[0]
table_body = table2.find_all('tbody')[0]
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    datalist2.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) # Get rid of empty values
```

The following code to export the tabulate output data into csv file

```
content2=tabulate(datalist2, tablefmt="tsv")
text_file=open("output.csv","w")
text_file.write(content2)
text_file.close()
```

Now, It also displays the long text.

The following code exports the datalist2 into CSV using 'numpy'

```
np.savetxt("output_np.csv", datalist2, delimiter=",", fmt='%s'
```

The following code exports the datalist2 into CSV using 'pandas'

```
my_df=pd.DataFrame(datalist2)
my_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Why is this answer down voted ? Explanation expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of default column width in pandas, which is 50. You can simply set it to the maximum length you expect or set it to -1 to disable column maximum width.

Add the following line before writing:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```

See the link for details:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html

Comment: I'm not accepting this solution because this solution does not show how to export the tabulate output data into csv file. It does not show how to remove 'NaN' and Index column.

Comment: Did that nan thing come after an edit? Remember the rule - use separate questions for separate issues.

Comment: NaN comes from the column which does not have any value. Table contains 3 columns. 2nd column had no values. In place of empty space, NaN is displayed.

Comment: @DipankarNalui Please go through SO guidelines regarding asking the question. You asked two questions within one (Handling NaN, and Truncating long values) - both of which are duplicates of existing questions. The first part of your question asks "There is a problem with this code. It does not show the long text." That's what I answered. Please follow the guidelines.